# Geometric (smooth) Rubik's cube

Tags: lie-groups, rubiks-cube

I and my friend are thinking about a smooth analog of Rubik's cube. One idea is the following:

Consider the 2-dimensional sphere $S^{2}$. We choose three parameters: $(L, H, \theta)$. Here $L$ is a ray that passes through the origin, $H$ is a plane that intersects with $L$, the sphere, and orthogonal to $L$. $\theta\in [0, 2\pi]$ is an angle that we will rotate the part of the sphere. Here is the picture for the action:

[image]

Now I have some question about a group $G$ generated by this action on $S^{2}$.

1. Is $G$ has finite dimensional Lie group? If it is, what is a dimension of the group?
2. Is there any interesting and nontrivial relation among elements? For example, in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, the composition of two rotations is also rotation. But our group clearly doesn't satisfy such things.

---

**Edit**. As Elkies said, this is an infinite dimensional group, since it contains an infinite dimensional abelian group (which is generated by elements with fixed $L$ and varying $H\&\theta$. But we may think about some subgroups that seem to be finite dimensional, or even finite.

Before we do that, there's some minor problem with the definition of $G$ that Jim Conant mentioned. I want to ignore the action that only moves measure 0 parts, such as an equator. 
To do this, for any two functions $g_{1}, g_{2}:S^{2} \to S^{2}$ we can define an equivalence relation as 
$$
g_{1}\sim g_{2} \text{ iff } \{x\in S^{2}\,:\, g_{1}(x) \neq g_{2}(x)\} \text{ has a measure 0}
$$
Now consider the quotient of the group by this equivalence relation, then we will get more reasonable group. There's some reason why I'm thinking this reasonable - there are some subgroups that I want to think about.

1. Assume that we only allow "semi-sphere turns". So we consider the subgroup of $G$ where the plane $H$ should pass the origin. 
   Is this a finite-dimensional group? I think $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is a codimension 1 subgroup of this semi-sphere-turn group, but I'm not sure about it.
2. What will be the finite subgroups of this $G$? There's a natural but nontrivial way to construct a finite subgroup of $G$: to think *real* Rubik's cube type puzzles. For example, put Rubik's cube in the center of the sphere and cur the sphere along the planes that correspond to the Rubik's cube's slice faces (I hope you understand what I mean), and turn the pieces along the axis of the cube. In other words, this is a subgroup that is isomorphic to the group of Rubik's cube. We can do the same thing with Pyraminx, Metaminx, Dogic, Skewb, or any regular polytope. I want to know if these covers all the possible finite subgroups of $G$.
3. How about higher dimensional spheres, or other highly symmetric manifolds (such as a torus or hyperbolic spaces)?

Comment: That's a huge group $-$ certainly not finite-dimensional,
because the transformations with $L$ fixed 
already generate an infinite-dimensional abelian subgroup.

Comment: What happens at $S^2\cap H$? Does that part move?

Comment: Though this is large as a group, it is a reasonably natural piece of a groupoid / pseudogroup consisting of open subsets of the sphere and isometries between them.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudogroup

Comment: It presumably has the property that its finite subgroups are exactly the groups corresponding to doctrinaire twisty puzzles. ("Doctrinaire" being the term used by the members of http://twistypuzzles.com/forum to refer to a puzzle whose moves form a group, like the Rubik's cube.) I don't know what other interesting properties it might have.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thank you for the comment. I added some questions that I forgot to ask.

Comment: @JimConant I just edited the question. In summary, I want to ignore such small movements.

Comment: @Nathaniel I agree with that and it was one of the motivations of the question. Is it possible to prove it?

Comment: @SeewooLee I realised there are some counterexamples. For example, puzzles like the Bubbloids, whose axes don't intersect in a single point, can't be represented this way. But if we restrict ourselves to puzzles that can be made in the shape of a sphere, then it should work. As you say in the edited question, it's clear that all such puzzles correspond to finite subgroups of this group, so we only have to determine whether the group has any 'pathological' finite subgroups that don't correspond to physically implementable puzzles. I would be interested to know the answer to that.

Comment: Note that there are finite subgroups that do not correspond to regular polyhedrons, such as the ones discussed here http://twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31829. (You will have to sign up for an account to see most of the images.) Also note that there are plenty of infinite subgroups that are generated by only a finite set of the generators. (These are called "jumbling" puzzles.) See for example http://twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25752 (the images are missing for the first few pages of that post, but if you keep reading you will be able to see what they are discussing.)

Comment: (I mention this because I think there are interesting unexplored mathematical possibilities hinted at in those threads.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "semi-sphere turn subgroup" is not finite-dimensional. For any convex polygon on the sphere, you can look at the subgroup generated by "semi-sphere turns" along its edges; infinitesimally, these should be linearly independent.

Comment: Let $r(L,H,\theta)$ be the partial rotation defined at the beginning. Do you implicitly define $G$ as the subgroup generated by all such partial rotations (for all $(L,H,\theta)$?). It's not clear to me but it seems the interpretation made by other users.

Comment: Elkies didn't say it's an infinite dimensional Lie group, but that it contains an infinite-dimensional Lie group... anyway to be an infinite-dimensional Lie group requires defining some "good" group topology and proving that it's Lie, and both steps are unclear here.

Comment: I tend to guess that this group is dense in the group of volume-preserving self-homeomorphisms of the round 2-sphere.

Comment: @YCor, aren't these partial rotations discontinous? I don't see a map to the homeo group...

Comment: @EBz yes, I'm stupid. I should say the group of measure preserving automorphisms of the sphere. But I should be careful which topology one considers on this group. One such topology is the topology induced by the bi-invariant distance $d(f,g)$ = measure of $\{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\}$.

Comment: @YCor OK makes sense and actually is an interesting q, tho I'm inclined to disagree that it's dense at first glance. Nonetheless everything is so huge here my intuition isn't much to go by. In partic we can just cut out arbitrary positive measure chunks and stick them back on somewhere else...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the action on the equator of the subgroup preserving the equator ‘contains’ the action of the interval exchange transformation group. In fact, I belive this stays true if look at the action on a (possibly infinite) collection of disjoint circles, provided each of them is at positive distance from the others. That group is big.

Comment: @YCor Yes, your definition of $G$ is what I intended. Honestly, I didn't think about the topology seriously but I think the metric topology that you suggested is somehow the most natural way to give a topology. Also, I don't know why $G$ should be a dense subgroup of the measure-preserving automorphism group of $S^{2}$.

Comment: @PierrePC I think that is almost the same as Elkies' argument, isn't it? Anyway, that also show that the group should be very big.

Comment: @Nathaniel Thank you for such interesting examples!

Comment: But most likely, dense or not dense, this topology is certainly not complete, so not what we like of a "Lie group". Another topology, closer to topological dynamics would be the one induced by the action on the Boolean algebra generated by spherical caps.